# How to select multiple objects on MOUSE_OVER during a MOUSE_DOWN

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Lets say I have 30 objects created in for loop, added to a container.
Objects stop on frame 1. I have added event listeners to the objects as you can see below, and when I click any object inside container, it goes to frame 2 and play.

```
for (var i:int=0; i < 30; i++)
{
    var object = new Object1();
    object.gotoAndStop(1);
    object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
    container.addChild(object);
}

private function myFunction(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

So I have to click each object to send it on frame 2, 
I also tried ROLL_OVER, everything is same but `CLICK` is changed to `ROLL_OVER` inside for loop.

What I want is to click, and then mouse over object so they go to frame 2 and play.

The problem is that I need to use `MOUSE_DOWN` event, I have tried to set `MOUSE_DOWN` instead of `CLICK` or `ROLL_OVER`, but it does not work. If I want to send objects to frame 2 (using `MOUSE_DOWN`), I need to click each of them, there is no difference between `MOUSE_DOWN` and `CLICK` in this case.

As someone who does not know much about mouse events, I'm wondering why roll over and click works, but mouse_down does not?

Comment: This is usually due to `e.currentTarget` not being what you expect.  What do you see in the log if you put `trace(e.currentTarget);` in your `myFuntion`?

Comment: It says [object Tile], and this Tile is actually Object1 you can see in for loop.

Comment: @Brian - `e.currentTarget` will be the object the listener was attached to - in this case the object stored in the var `object`.  `e.target` on the other hand will be whatever was actually clicked (be it the same as current target, or a child of it that bubbled the event up the current target)

Comment: I think you may need to show more code.  There is nothing to indicate a problem in what you've shown.  Do you have any code inside the `Object1` class?  Something that could be cancelling click/mouse down events?

Comment: I do not even have Object1 class, I just have a MovieClip Object1, it contains many many sprites. And mouse click works, but mouse down does not work, actually it works same as mouse click,that's weird to me.

Comment: "It works the same as mouse click" - Do you mean that when you use `MOUSE_DOWN` it doesn't fire until after the mouse button is released?  - side note:  use @UserHandle if replying to comments, that way the person gets an alert

Comment: PO is probably mistaken and is expecting mousedown to not fire on mousedown. His comparison of rollover to mousedown is an indication.

Comment: @LDMS Actually not exactly same as CLICK, when using MOUSE_DOWN, it fires when I press mouse, but only for one object. Then I need to release and press again. So it is very similar to CLICK, just MOUSE_DOWN fires before CLICK.

Comment: That is normal...   Mouse down fires when the mouse button is pressed.  Click on the other hand fires after a mouse down and mouse up sequence. (so CLICK will only fire after the mouse up and only if the same object had a mouse down prior)

Comment: I have 30 objects in line and I want to press mouse and move mouse over all objects and send them to frame 2. Just like drawing. I want to make it with one move, do not want to click each object. That's the point, but seems I will need to use CLICK.

Comment: I see, your finally making sense now.  The answer by @thefailsafe below should do what you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do... you want to press the mouse to start drawing over a bunch of sprites, each one goes to frame two when you mouse over it, but only if the mouse button is pressed, right?

try something like this

```
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setMouseDown);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, setMouseUp);
private var mouseIsDown:Boolean = false;
private var currentSprite:Sprite;

for (var i:int=0; i < 30; i++)
{
    var object = new Object1();
    object.gotoAndStop(1);
    object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, myFunction);
    object.mouseChildren = false;
    container.addChild(object);
}

private function setMouseDown(e:MouseEvent){
    mouseIsDown = true;
    setActive(currentSprite);
}

private function setMouseUp(e:MouseEvent){
    mouseIsDown = false;
}

private function myFunction(e:MouseEvent){
    currentSprite = e.target;
    if(mouseIsDown){
        setActive(currentSprite);
    }
}

private function setActive(target:Sprite){
    target.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you understand the situation :) It works,but it does not trigger when I press mouse, I have to move mouse. For example if I click mouse (it is down) but nothing happens. I can add event listener for CLICK and it will work, but in that case I need 2 functions (and they are not so simple as you can see in the example). Do have any better solution? Anyways I can accept your answer.

Comment: Try the edit above, you'll need to keep track of the current object under the mouse, and then on mouse down make that one go to frame 2, as well as the rest you move over.